# Detect what process/program start my process/program

Tags: c#, .net, c++, vb6

Is there a way in code to detect what process or application starts my process or application. Any .net, vb6 or c++ code snips would be great

Comment: google terms i recommend (but haven't tried): windows find process parent... my logic is that Linux maintains the pid of this processes' parent, so maybe windows does the same.

Answer (score 1):

In .Net,

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
```

returns the assembly that the current running assembly process was kicked off from.   But if you have more than one process running, I don't believe there is any way to determine which one was the first one to start up...

to get the version of the entry assembly,

```
 Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as a basis [Taking a Snapshot and Viewing Processes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686701(VS.85).aspx). And traverse all the way down to the root process!

Answer (score 1):

James Brown shows in his **"ProcessTree"** snippet how to do this:

http://www.catch22.net/content/snippets

Although the code is very C-ish it is very clean and good to understand.

He is basically doing a call to `ZwQuerySystemInformation()` which returns a `SYSTEM_PROCESSES` structure in the second argument. This structure holds information about the process incl. a member called `InheritiedFromProcessId` which is the parent processes ID.

Comment: Just remind that ZwQuerySystemInformation is not part of the Windows SDK, it is a NTDLL function and may be modified or even just removed from future Windows versions[1].


[1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725506(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class ParentProc { 

[DllImport("KERNEL32.dll")] //[DllImport("toolhelp.dll")] 
public static extern int CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(uint flags, uint processid); 

[DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL")] //[DllImport("toolhelp.dll")] 
public static extern int CloseHandle(int handle); 

[DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL")] //[DllImport("toolhelp.dll") 
public static extern int Process32Next(int handle, ref ProcessEntry32 pe); 

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
public struct ProcessEntry32 { 
public uint dwSize; 
public uint cntUsage; 
public uint th32ProcessID; 
public IntPtr th32DefaultHeapID; 
public uint th32ModuleID; 
public uint cntThreads; 
public uint th32ParentProcessID; 
public int pcPriClassBase; 
public uint dwFlags; 
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=256)] public string szExeFile; 
}; 

public static Process FindParentProcess() { 

int SnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(0x00000002, 0); //2 = SNAPSHOT of all procs 
try{ 
ProcessEntry32 pe32 = new ProcessEntry32(); 
pe32.dwSize = 296; 
int procid = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id; 
while(Process32Next(SnapShot, ref pe32) != 0) { 
string xname = pe32.szExeFile.ToString(); 
if(procid==pe32.th32ProcessID) { 
return System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(Convert.ToInt32(pe32.th32ParentProcessID)); 
} 
} 

}catch(Exception ex){ 
throw new Exception(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod() + " failed! [Type:"+ex.GetType().ToString()+", Msg:"+ex.Message+"]"); 
}finally{ 
CloseHandle(SnapShot); 
} 
return null; 
} 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not the big issue here, you could also use WMI and thus stay 100% managed (C#/VB.NET) if you care.

Example (just the WMI queries, actual C#/VB.NET code omitted):

```
   // First get figure the ID of your parent process
   SELECT ParentProcessID FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessID = <MYPROCESSID>

   // Than use that the get any attribute, e.g. the Name, of it
   SELECT Name FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessID = <PARENTPROCESSID>
```